# How do I make Octave see installed Shogun libraries in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: octave, shogun

I copied the commands (from these instructions: http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/install#ubuntu) into the terminal  and they seem to have worked, but there is no documentation on how to make Octave find the libraries. I have tried modshogun and init_shogun but Octave cannot find them. I do have the libraries in usr/lib, and I have put that directory on PATH. I have even set usr/lib as my working directory in Octave and that did not help. As far as I have found, there is no Shogun documentation on what to do at this point.

I have also tried compiling Shogun from source, but configure couldn't find GCC. Apparently, this is a known problem with newer versions of GCC. I decided to ask for help with the former method because at least I have the libraries with that.

Edit: I am following the instructions here http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/install#manual-basics

When i do cd build and then "cmake -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON" it tells me there is no cmakelists.txt. There is one in in the above folder, but when I go to that directory and do "cmake -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON" again, it tells me "Shogun can only be built with GPL codes if the source files are in /home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/src/gpl. Please download or disable with LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF."

However, when I add -LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF as an option, i get the error "CMake Error: The source directory "/home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/-LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF" does not exist."

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and if possible some minimal code. As your question currently looks, I do not see much information which helps people answer it. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!

Comment: What part of my problem description needs clarification? In what way would adding code help?

Answer (score 1):

You've [linked](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/install#ubuntu) to the Ubuntu install instructions. From there

> These currently do contain the C++ library and Python bindings..

No word that this would include the GNU Octave binding. See below on the same page:

> The native C++ interface is always included. The cmake options for building interfaces are -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON -DINTERFACE_R .. etc. For example, replace the cmake step above by cmake -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON...

So you have to grab the source and fire up cmake with something like `-DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON`

Steps to build the bleeding edge of shogun (the github repo) and the Octave interface:

```
git clone https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun && cd shogun
git submodule update --init
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON
make -j4
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Andy. I've followed the instructions under Basics but when i do cd build and then "cmake -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON" it tells me there is no cmakelists.txt. There is one in in the above folder, but when I go to that directory and do "cmake -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON" again, it tells me "Shogun can only be built with GPL codes if the source files are in /home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/src/gpl. Please download or disable with LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF."

Comment: However, when I add -LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF as an option, i get the error "CMake Error: The source directory "/home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/-LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF" does not exist."

Comment: Edit: I meant to write -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON instead of -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON.

Comment: I guess you forgot the ".." (which means the cmakelists.txt is on dir above) and to init the submodules...

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting the error: 

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (MESSAGE):
  Shogun can only be built with GPL codes if the source files are in
  /home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/src/gpl.  Please download or disable with
  LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF.
and when I try the command:

cmake .. -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON -LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF

It says:

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/derose/shogun/src/shogun/build/-LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF" does not exist.

How can I download those GPL codes so that it will stop bothering me about them?

Comment: You know what, maybe I got confused with the folder structure. before i was in shogun/src/shogun/build and things were not working, but i backed out to the first shogun and made build there, and now I'm in shogun/build. I retried the cmake command and got a lot further, but now the problem is "Could NOT find Octave (missing: OCTAVE_ROOT_DIR) (found suitable version
  "4.4.1", minimum required is "3.6")" Somehow it knows the version and yet cannot find it.

Comment: How did you install GNU Octave 4.4.1? From which repo od ppa, from source? Are you sure you have the headers or -dev package installed?